# jquery datatable custom filters do not redraw the table until user interacts with the table

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have jquery datatable that has a custom filter applied to it that filters the rows based on the month and year.

The custom filter that I have applied doesnot redraw the table until I interact with the table after applying filter such as by typing in the search bar or sorting the rows from default sorting buttons in the in the column heads.

datatable is being populated by a php `foreach` loop that recieves data from a database. This is actually a view of a CodeIgnitor project.

This is my custom filter:

`#month` and `#year` are ids of two `html` `select` inputs.

```html
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
            var month = parseInt($('#month').val(), 10);
            var year = parseInt($('#year').val(), 10);
            var date = data[0].split('-');

            if (parseInt(date[1], 10) == month && parseInt(date[0], 10) == year)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    );

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#expenseList').DataTable();

        $('#month, #year').keyup( function() {
            table.draw();
        });
    });
```

whenever I select a month or year the datatable remains unaffected until I interact with some other default functionality of the table such as search or the sorting buttons.

**EDIT:**

Filters are html `select` menus given as:

```html
<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Company:</td>
            <td>
                <select id="company" name="company">
                    <option value="" selected> Select </option>
                    <?php foreach($data['company'] as $c) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $c->id; ?>"> <?php echo $c->company_name; ?> </option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Select Month/Year:</td>
            <td>
                <select id="month" name="month">
                    <?php 
                        $month = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
                        for($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) { 
                            if(date('m') == $i+1) { ?>
                                <option value=<?php echo $i+1; ?> selected> <?php echo $month[$i]; ?> </option>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <option value=<?php echo $i+1; ?>> <?php echo $month[$i]; ?> </option>
                    <?php } } ?>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="year" name="year">
                    <?php
                        for($i = 2000; $i < 2100; $i++) { 
                            if(date("Y") == $i) { ?>
                                <option value=<?php echo $i; ?> selected> <?php echo $i; ?> </option>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <option value=<?php echo $i; ?>> <?php echo $i; ?> </option>
                        <?php } } ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is that I'm using a `select`s. With simple `input` fields it works fine.

Comment: I tried `$('#month, #year').change()` instead of `$('#month, #year').keyup()` and it works fine, the problem is maybe I'm listening to an incorrect event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working perfectly fine for input-elements. But if you use `select`-elements you should listen for the `change`-event:

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
    let month = parseInt($('#month').val(), 10);
    let year = parseInt($('#year').val(), 10);
    let date = data[0].split('-');
    
    if (parseInt(date[1], 10) == month && parseInt(date[0], 10) == year) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
);

$(document).ready(function() {
  let table = $('#expenseList').DataTable();
  $('#month, #year').on('change', function(event) {
    table.draw();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Month:
<select id="month" name="month">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  <option value="3">March</option>
  <option value="4">April</option>
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="6">June</option>
  <option value="7">July</option>
  <option value="8">August</option>
  <option value="9">September</option>
  <option value="10">October</option>
  <option value="11">November</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<br>
Year: 
<select id="year" name="year">
  <option value="2018">2018</option>
  <option value="2019" selected="selected">2019</option>
</select>
<br>

<table id="expenseList">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Date</th><th>Description</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>2018-12-31</td><td>Test 1234</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2019-01-01</td><td>I dont know!</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2019-01-02</td><td>Another...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2019-02-01</td><td>Apple</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2019-03-01</td><td>Banana</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2019-04-01</td><td>Coconut</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2019-05-01</td><td>Donut</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2019-06-05</td><td>Lorem Ipsum</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've found a solution and posted a comment above, can you add it to your answer and any other suggestions.

Comment: Sure, i've updated the answer and example. To listen for the `change`-event is a better choice when using `select`-elements. But if you would use an `input`-element (like you first described in your question) the better approach would be to listen for the `key*`-events, because the `change`-event would behave different on them.